# Class models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and consistency results

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

First of all, I'm only starting to study independence results in set theory. And there is one obstacle that confuses me a lot. Probably such questions have already been asked, but I haven't found anything that clarifies it for me. I'm new to that subject, so please feel free to correct me if I'm using wrong terminology or reasoning.

Here is how I understand the reasoning behind proving that a statement $\varphi$ is not a theorem of a theory $T$. From mathematical logic we know that $T \not\vdash \varphi$ if and only if $\mbox{Con}(T + \neg \varphi)$. From Gödel's Completeness theorem it follows that $\mbox{Con}(T)$ if and only if $T$ has a model (that is a **set** with a collection of operations, relations and constants). So in order to prove something like $\mathsf{ZFC} \not\vdash \mathsf{CH}$ we should produce a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{CH}$. On the other hand, by Gödel's Incompleteness theorem this can't be done inside $\mathsf{ZFC}$. So all consistency results should be relative and be of the form $$\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}) \rightarrow \mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \varphi).$$

As I've understood, when the method of forcing is used, we start with the assumption like $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ that gives us a (set) model $(M, \in)$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ from which (using Löwenheim–Skolem theorem) we can get a countable model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. After that we extend this model to another model $(N, \in)$ that satisfies some desired statement $\varphi$ obtaining a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \varphi$. Such reasoning looks perfectly fine to me, since we are working with **set** models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ whose existence is based on the assumption $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$.

The question is about **class** models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. For example, there is the Gödel's constructible universe $L$ that is a model for $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$ (and also for $\mathsf{AC}$ and $\mathsf{CH}$). My main question is

> How can we formally deduce from the existence of such a (class) model that $$\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L)?$$
>   In other words, how the existence of a class model for $T$ implies $\mbox{Con}(T)$?

Is there some kind of Gödel's completeness theorem for **class** models? Or again we are starting with some **set** model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and constructing $L$ inside it? If so, how this changes the proof of that $L$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? It seems like I'm missing some basic fact (and commonly used technique) that allows to go from class models to set models. I would be very grateful if someone could explain me in details how this issue is resolved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer: we can't. What we are actually doing is taking a *set* model $M$ of ZFC and then we prove that $L^M$, which is the constructible universe of $M$, is a model of $ZFC+V=L$. So this is still a result of the sort $Con(ZFC)\Rightarrow Con(ZFC+V=L)$.

Comment: This might be relevant, maybe even a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557924/why-do-class-sized-models-escape-the-completeness-theorem

Comment: I totally understand that all consistency results are relative (I explicitly wrote it in my question). My question is how to obtain such a result using a class model $L$? @Wojowu: Is this an obvious corollary of the fact that $L$ is a class model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or it requires different reasoning?

Comment: A class model is a set model in the meta-theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The theorem that $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ implies $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF+\mathit{V=L})$ is a *meta-theorem*.

It is formulated in the meta-theory, and not internally. You are absolutely right that we can't quite formulate this *internally* without violating Godel's incompleteness theorem. But the nice thing is that what we can prove is that for every axiom $\varphi$ of $\sf ZFC$, $\sf ZF\vdash\varphi^L$, where $L$ is the class defined via the axiom of constructibility.

So while $\sf ZF$ does not prove that $L\models\sf ZFC$, it does prove that every axiom of $\sf ZF$ is relatively true. This tells us even a bit more than just the meta-theorem, which is great.

Comment: So the statement "for every axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $\mathsf{ZF} \vdash \varphi^L$" has nothing to do with the relative consistency result "$\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF})$ implies $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF} + V = L)$"? My question is how from the first statement (that every axiom of $\mathsf{ZF}$ is true relative to $L$) we can deduce the second? I've seen statements like $L$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$, hence as a corollary we have the relative consistency result. Is it an obvious corollary?

Comment: Well, it has something to do with it. If we assume *in the meta-theory* that $\sf ZF$ is consistent, we immediately get that the meta-theory cannot possibly think that $\sf ZF$ proves a false statement. So we get that $\sf ZFC+\it V=L$ is also consistent. This is stronger than saying that the proof happens entirely in the meta-theory.

Comment: I'm sorry, may be I'm asking unclear questions, but my questions is: how do we prove that $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$ is also consistent? We know that  there is a class model of it (namely, $L$). Assume that $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF})$, so there is a **set** model $(M, \in)$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$. How can we use $L$ and this model to produce a **set** model for $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$?

Comment: I don't think I understand. $Con(ZF)$ is an arithmetic statement and it can be stated in language of $ZF$, isn't that so?

Comment: We can prove that $L$ satisfies every axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$ (without **set** models and all that stuff). How the relative consistency result follows from it? Is this relative consistency result another difficult theorem or it is just an easy corollary of it?

Comment: @Asaf: "If we assume in the meta-theory that ZF is consistent, we immediately get that the meta-theory cannot possibly think that ZF proves a false statement." Is that a specific property of ZF? For example, it doesn't seem to hold about ZFC: if our meta-theory is ZF+Con(ZFC)+not-AC, then the meta-theory thinks ZFC is consistent, but also thinks that ZFC proves (trivially) the statement AC which the meta-theory thinks is false ...

Comment: UGH! Everyone, calm down. I can only write so many comments at a single time! :-)

Comment: @Henning: You're right.

Comment: @Wojowu: So what?

Comment: @Random Jack: The point is that relative consistency is a *meta-theorem* proved in the *meta-theory*. It is not internal to $\sf ZF$, but rather external to it. If your meta-theory is a set theory, then the proof literally constructs a model *in the meta-theory* witnessing the consistency. If your meta-theory is arithmetical, then the fact that there is such proof for each axiom (or finitely many at a time) shows that if $\sf ZFC+\it V=L$ would prove $0=1$, so must $\sf ZF$ prove that $0=1$ as both theories agree one what is $0$ and what is $1$.

Comment: I think the problem might be with me not really understanding what "internally" means, because I thought that it means precisely that $Con(ZF)$ is expressible in the language of $ZF$ (and from context I infer it's not what that means).

Comment: @Wojowu: You are correct it is a number theoretic statement that can be formulated in set theory. But In this context it is a statement in the meta-theory, rather than the theory.

Comment: I see your point. I have never went into all of this theory/meta-theory distinction, so I'm not going to spend time talking about it here in comments.

Comment: @Asaf: I think that I understand the difference between the theory and the meta-theory, but "the proof is literally constructs a model..." is what confuses me. Here is more specific question, which I hope will make my global question more clear. In Kunen's "Set theory" there is a theorem ($\mathsf{ZF}$): *$L$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZF} + V = L$*. Right after that without proof and any reasoning comes the corollary: *$\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF}) \rightarrow \mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF} + V = L)$*. My question is how this corollary is deduced from the theorem?

Comment: @Random: If our meta-theory is a set theory, then stating that $\sf ZF$ is consistent is the same as saying that it has a *set* model *in the meta-theory*. From this set model we carve out a set model of $V=L$ which witnesses the consistency of $\sf ZFC+\it V=L$. That's the idea.

Comment: @Asaf: It is the point of my question. Is this an obvious procedure? If not why there is no proof of this corollary (and many other results in this book are of this form: there is a theorem stating that some proper class is a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$ + something, and right after that there is a corollary (without proof) stating the relative consistency result).

Comment: @Random Jack: Yes, it is as obvious as it gets in the case the meta-theory is a set theory. You have a set, and you define a subset and literally prove that all the axioms of $\sf ZFC+\it V=L$ are satisfied by that set. Therefore *you have a model*, the fact is that this a set in the meta-theory is all we need to conclude that the theory is consistent. If the meta-theory is an arithmetic theory you need to work slightly harder to conclude that if $\sf ZFC+\it V=L$ proves that $0=1$ then actually $\sf ZF$ proves that $0=1$, which is exactly the relative consistency statement we want.

Comment: @Asaf: Ok,I hope this will be the last question. So assume $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF})$, then there is a **set** model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZF}$. Inside this model we can define the constructible universe $L^M$ and prove that $L^M$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZF} + V = L$ so $\mbox{Con}(\mathsf{ZF} + V = L)$ follows. Is this reasoning correct? I don't quite understand how our proof of $L$ is a **class** model of $\mathsf{ZF} + V = L$ trivially implies $L^M$ is a **set** model of $\mathsf{ZF} + V = L$.

Comment: @Random Jack: Because the statement "$L$ is a class model of $T$" means that what we have proved is that in the meta-theory every axiom of $T$ holds in $L$. Which is literally saying that $L^M$ is a set model of $T$ in the meta-theory.

Comment: @Asaf: I think I finally got it. Thank you for your thorough explanation!